# To check whether files have been removed from folder?

Tags: c#

I have two files in a folder(their extension are ended with AD and AC), which these two files automatically will remove from the folder by another program. I would like to check as soon as these two files were removed from the folder put a message that shows that these files have been removed.

```
                DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(folder);
                FileInfo[] AFiles = dir.GetFiles("*AD");
                FileInfo[] BFiles = dir.GetFiles("*AC");

                while (AFiles.Count() != 0 && BFiles.Count() != 0)
                {
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(50000);
                    Console.WriteLine("Please Wait...");

                    while (AFiles.Count() == 0 && BFiles.Count() == 0)
                    {

                        Console.WriteLine("Done.. both files have been removed");
                    }
                }
```

But when both files are removed, in the second while loop the AFile and BFile count is equal to 1 and the program ignores the second while loop and just do the first while loop again and again. If you have any idea please let me know.
Thanks

Comment: Maybe [`FileSystemWatcher`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher(v=vs.110).aspx) would work more efficiently

Comment: @Mango same suggestion, just beware of using them on networkshares, had some rather dissapointing results a year back or so

Answer (score 0):

You need to reset the values in the arrays inside the loop or else you'll always be using the first values set even when the files have changed:

```
DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(folder);
FileInfo[] AFiles = dir.GetFiles("*AD");
FileInfo[] BFiles = dir.GetFiles("*AC");

while (AFiles.Count() != 0 && BFiles.Count() != 0)
{
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(50000);
    Console.WriteLine("Please Wait...");

    AFiles = dir.GetFiles("*AD");
    BFiles = dir.GetFiles("*AC");

    while (AFiles.Count() == 0 && BFiles.Count() == 0)
    {

        Console.WriteLine("Done.. both files have been removed");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. it solved my issue. I really appreciate that.